# Adding ShortHostName to hostname file, and ShortHostName.DOMAIN to hosts file in Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, hosts, hostname

When I use

```
docker run --it --name myContainer --hostname myShortHostName ubuntu bash
```

That will add `myShortHostName` to `/etc/hostname` file. And `172.169.X.X myShortHostName` in `/etc/hosts file`.

but in this case, I use `hostname -f` command to fetch my container's `FQDN`, because there is no `FQDN` entry in `/etc/hosts` file. And I cannot edit it because it gets replaced each time the container boots.

And if I used:

```
docker run --it --name myContainer --hostname myShortHostName.DOMAIN ubuntu bash
```

That will add the `FQDN` to `/etc/hostname` file, which is not the recommended convention by `hostname` rules, and it is not the convention I used to use in my system I am administrating.

> The recommended method of setting the FQDN is to make the hostname be an alias for the fully qualified name using /etc/hosts,
>          DNS, or NIS. For example, if the hostname was "ursula", one might have a line in /etc/hosts which reads
>
> ```
>          127.0.1.1    ursula.example.com ursula
> ```

Is there any way (actually I need ideal way, not editing the files with a script after booting the container) to only add the short `myShortHostName` to `/etc/hostname` file, and the FQDN to /etc/hosts file using `docker run` command or any Docker's built in commands or techniques?

What I need is to be able to get the ShortHostName by `hostname -s` or `hostname`, and the ShortHostName.DOMAIN (FQDN) by using `hostname -f` inside the Docker container without adding the FQDN to `/etc/hostname` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure the FQDN is added to /etc/hosts in your Docker container by passing the `--domainname` argument to your `docker run` command. For example running your container with the following command:

`docker run --it --name myContainer --hostname ursula --domainname example.com ubuntu bash`

will result in the following entry being created in /etc/hosts:

`172.169.X.X    ursula.example.com ursula`